# Electron dialog undefined in contextBridge

Tags: electron

#### Platform

- Electron - `12.0.8`
- Platform – macOS `10.15.7`

#### Description

I'm trying to display a file dialog from an Electron renderer process.  I thought I could reference the `dialog` object in the same way I reference `ipcRenderer` through the `contextBridge`.

```js
// preload.ts

const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, dialog } = require('electron');
import type { IpcRendererEvent } from 'electron';

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'ipc',
  {
    send: (channel: string, data: string[]) => {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
    },
    on: (channel: string, func: (evt: IpcRendererEvent, args: any) => void) => {
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, func);
    },
    chooseFile: (title: string) => dialog.showOpenDialogSync({
      title, properties: ['openFile']})
  }
)
```

But when I invoke `window.ipc.chooseFile('Some Title')`, I receive an error:

> Cannot read property 'showOpenDialogSync' of undefined

This seems to indicate that the `dialog` reference is not conveyed through
the `contextBridge` proxy.  Yet the first two functions that convey `ipcRenderer` work. The [exposeInMainWorld documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#api-functions) warns us that not every type can be proxied.

#### Notes

1. I understand that the generality of the three functions in my example undermines the security purpose of context isolation.  I'm just trying to determine what works *before* I invest too much time designing a detailed message passing scheme.
2. I understand I can implement this function in the **main process** and invoked it through IPC.  I'm fine with that.  I'm just curious why an `ipcRenderer` reference is successfully proxied through the `contextBridge` but `dialog` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't one of proxying through the `contextBridge`, but one of which Electron APIs are available in the renderer process at all. Unfortunately `dialog` just isn't one of those ([note "Process: Main" on its page](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog)), so it can't be referenced directly in the renderer process, even during preload. The old [`remote` API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) for using main process modules from the renderer process is still available, but it rightly warns you that

> The `remote` module is deprecated. Instead of `remote`, use `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain`.

So yes, your solution in note (2) is the intended one.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I just needed to be slapped.  That's why the dialog API is listed under Main Process Modules on the documentation page.